# Как привязаться к событию внутри iframe

Tags: jquery, javascript

Делаю так.

```
$('#iframe').load(function(){

                $(this).contents().find('body').bind('callmod',function(){

                    alert('Yahoooo!!!!');

                });
});
```

И в самом фрейме уже создаю событие

```
$('body').trigger('callmod');
```

И короче не работает.

Если цепляюсь стандартным, click тогда работает, а свои события почемуто ну никак не вяжет...

Answer (score 1):

Сори за ложную тервогу, отыскал в чем дело, нажеюсь комуто это тоже будет полезно.

Все дело в том что я в фрейм подгрузил свою jQuery, соответственно, это совершенно разные экземпляры объектов. Поэтому, решается все достаточно просто.

```
$(document).bind('callmod',function(){

                    alert('Yahoooo!!!!');

                });
```

В самом фрейме.

```
parent.$(parent.document).trigger('callmod');
```

Comment: можешь скинуть код с этим решением? Не могу использовать такое у себя